# How can I group multiple columns into an object when making a database call in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I am fetching users

Each user has 10 columns associated with it

How can I group 5 columns together into an object on each user so I can more easily map over them with javascript?

I could do

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
   $user['new_object']['col_1'] = $user->col_1;
   unset($user->col_1);
   $user['new_object']['col_2'] = $user->col_2;
   // etc 
}
```

But surely there is a way to group columns into an object on Laravel?

For example, something like

```
$users = User::where('verified', 1)
             ->group('new_object', ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']),
             ->get();
```

Or is there a way for me to update my User model to do this?

Comment: Use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) to manipulate data within the PHP. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutators in your model:

```
public function getNewObjAttribute() {
    return [
        $this->col1,
        $this->col2,
        $this->col3,
    ];
}
```

And in `$appends` attribute inside that model:

```
protected $appends = [
    'new_obj',
];
```

Comment: Also remember to add protected $hidden = ['col_1', 'col_2']; to avoid duplication

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
$users = User::where('verified', 1)->get()->map(function($row)
{
    $row->new_obj = [$row->col1, $row->col2, $row->col3];
    unset($row->col1, $row->col2, $row->col3);
    return $row;
});
```

Comment: That works but I was hoping not to have to map / loop over all of them and build this query on the fly. Also, how to drop the columns that are now grouped?

Comment: See my updated solution. Looping over the items is that expensive (well as long as you do not have zillions of them)

Comment: Good call on the unset. Happy to give this the correct answer for now until a refactor comes along ;-) Thank you!